# Mint 19 package install and update error message for minecraft-installer

Tags: linux-mint, dpkg, minecraft

Using Linux Mint 19 after installing Minecraft I get the error below after every install or update:

`minecraft-installer package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 8`

Tried `sudo dpkg --configure -D 777 minecraft-installer` which seems to show an issue with resources required by the post installer not being accessible.

```
--2019-05-11 13:56:48--  http://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/Minecraft.jar
Resolving s3.amazonaws.com (s3.amazonaws.com)... 52.216.164.157
Connecting to s3.amazonaws.com (s3.amazonaws.com)|52.216.164.157|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 280212 (274K) [application/java-archive]
Saving to: ‘/tmp/minecAJyWvp.jar’

/tmp/minecAJyWvp.ja 100%[===================>] 273.64K   457KB/s    in 0.6s    

2019-05-11 13:56:49 (457 KB/s) - ‘/tmp/minecAJyWvp.jar’ saved [280212/280212]

URL transformed to HTTPS due to an HSTS policy
--2019-05-11 13:56:49--  https://www.minecraft.net/android-icon-192x192.png
Resolving www.minecraft.net (www.minecraft.net)... 2606:2800:233:18f9:1142:8f:20aa:11e2, 152.199.20.92
Connecting to www.minecraft.net (www.minecraft.net)|2606:2800:233:18f9:1142:8f:20aa:11e2|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2019-05-11 13:56:49 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last line of the output/error message explains the problem.

```
2019-05-11 13:56:49 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

The URL is pointing to a resource that does not exist. Looks like a problem in the package/installer, or a file on the web has the wrong name/path. I suggest you contact support for the application itself and ask them.

[HTTP 404 Error - wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404)

Answer (score 0):

The path to the icon file: android-icon-192x192.png has changed.
Change the path of "android-icon-192x192.png" in file: /var/lib/dpkg/info/minecraft-intaller.postinst 
to:  https://my.minecraft.net/android-icon-192x192.png